# Adding custom stylesheet for different WordPress pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I created custom home page whose name is "front-page.php" and than added another page with custom css and JS files like this in the `header.php` file:

```
<?php 
function my_styles_method() {
        
    if (is_page_template('front-page.php'==TRUE){  
    // Register the style like this for a theme:  
    wp_register_style( 'my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/marquee.css');  

    // enqueue the stule  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style' );  
    
    }
    

    enter code here
    // Register the style like this for a theme:  
    if (is_page_template('our-story.php'==TRUE) {
    wp_register_style( 'my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/main.css');  

    // enqueue the stule  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style' );
    }
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' ); 

?>
```

Now, I face the following issues in this one:
when I run this in WordPress I get this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
> C:\wamp\www\wordpress_update\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\header.php
> on line 32

I have created custom templates on both the pages .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens around line 32 ?

Comment: line 32 is where the if statements { starts..

Comment: so ...  `if (is_page_template('front-page.php'==TRUE){ ` can you spot the error? PS: And the same goes for the 2nd if too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
    function my_styles_method() {

        if (is_page_template('front-page.php')==TRUE){  
        // Register the style like this for a theme:  
        wp_register_style( 'my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/marquee.css');  

        // enqueue the stule  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style' );  

        }


        //enter code here
        // Register the style like this for a theme:  
        if (is_page_template('our-story.php')==TRUE) {
        wp_register_style( 'my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/main.css');  

        // enqueue the stule  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style' );
        }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' ); 

    ?>
```

**// if (is_page_template('front-page.php'==TRUE) should be if (is_page_template('our-story.php')==TRUE)**

Comment: If you want appreciate then choose this answer as right answer

Comment: the problem I am facing now is that when I do this, my css file doesn't get picked up.. any idea why this is happening? css is inside includes folder and is named main.css

Comment: maybe get_template_directory_uri() doesn't return the correct path. Or the path you were expecting. have you tried to "debug" some value and some flux of code with some echo?